# How can I put more than one command in the same function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function but I know the error is I put two commands, first to fadein an element and hide other. How can I made this in correct mode?

```
$(maisJuridico).on("mousedown", function(){ 
    $(Juridico).fadeIn(); 
    $(menosJuridico).hide(); 
}, false);
```

Comment: what are these variables?

Comment: you haven't explained what expected behavior is. You can put any number of methods inside that event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as long as you're using jQuery, you don't need `.addEventListener`. You can bind your events with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

So, if you want the second method to be invoked after the `fadeIn` animation is finished, you can pass a `complete` callback function and call the second method from there.

Something like this:

```
(maisJuridico).on("mousedown", function(){ 
    $(Juridico).fadeIn({
       complete: function() {
            $(menosJuridico).hide(); 
       }
    }); 
}, false);
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/):

> ***.fadeIn( options )***
>
> **complete** 
>   *Type: Function()*
>
> A function that is called once the animation
>   on an element is complete.

---

Another [syntax](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/#fadeIn-duration-complete) is pass the `complete` callback as a second parameter. In this case, the first argument is `duration`. Like this:

```
$(Juridico).fadeIn(400, function() {
    $(menosJuridico).hide(); 
});
```

Comment: why mix native and jQuery methods?

Comment: @charlietfl it was not me that mixed, OP's original question was edited. Just pointed an answer. I will edit with this suggestion